# Prove an artificial variable that leaves the basis will never return.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

This is in the context of the Big M Method in the simplex algorithm in linear programming.

> Prove an artificial variable that leaves the basis will never return.

I have no idea how to start this. Anyone know any books with these kinds of questions(and proofs hopefully)?

The closest I could find is "[Topics in Linear Programming and Games Theory
 edited by Lakshmisree Bandopadhyaya](http://books.google.com.ph/books?id=Q_Y_ZsuDcoMC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=%22vector%20which%20is%20removed%20from%20the%20basis%22&source=bl&ots=_rpraao6rg&sig=XlINxS_kMo8TpMjPeLB8oNLEYPg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Bvd-VMX7POPAmQWUqoHwDQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22vector%20which%20is%20removed%20from%20the%20basis%22&f=false)" which seems to have a multivariate (i.e. vector) version of a question I had previously:

> The vector which leaves basis at one iteration cannot return to basis the next iteration.

Comment: This question seems to be about a specific algorithm for doing something-or-other. You should probably identify that algorithm in the question.

Comment: @henning done and thanks :))

Comment: First understand the Question you are asking.  Artificial variables are [introduced in the first phase](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ff271/teaching/opt/notes/notes8.pdf) of a two-phase simplex method in order to drive the tableau to a basic feasible solution.

Comment: @hardmath Of course intuitively it makes sense. The problem is how to prove it

Comment: How did you define the phase I algorithm? I think that the answer to your question follows immediately, as the algorithm simply doesnt consider artificial variables as pivoting Elements.

Answer (score -1):

Suppose you have a maximization problem. When a variable **x** enters basis and **y** leaves out of basis, it means that increasing **x** would increase the output of the objective function. But the objective function has the coefficients of **`-M`**  for artificial variables. So we cannot increase objective function value by increasing the artificial variable as it will decrease the current objective function output by a value of **`-M`** and become infeasible. Hence why the artificial variables cannot enter your basis once they originally left